# Symfony2: postgres database access denied

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I started learning Symfony2 and I wanted to use Doctrine to create table in my postgres database. I installed postgres and followed this steps:

`sudo -i -u postgres`

I've created user with name: test and type superuser
`createuser --interactive`

`createdb test`

I created user test with password test

`adduser test`

And my parameters.yml in symfony2 looks like this:

`parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: test
    database_user: test
    database_password: test
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null`

Also I have entity like this:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;
}
```

Then I typed this commend in terminal:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

And I got this warning:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for us  
  er 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)                                  


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                          
  SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using pas  
  sword: YES)                                                                  


  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using pas  
  sword: YES)
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I realized that I'm connected to mysql database and I don't know why. How can I change this?

Comment: Please check your `config.yml` file and more specifically the part where your configure the `doctrine` dbal connection. You can use the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) to see what config does what.

Answer (score 2):

One of our developper encountered this issue last week.

Your parameters.yml seems to be good, but if you have the "standard" config.yml, it don't specify the database_driver

```
#app/config/config.yml
[...]
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%" # <---- Add this line ;)
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
[...]
```